# undefined reference to `elast_opt()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I've written some oop code that use dealii library.

class `elastic` is defined in prelim header as:

```
using namespace dealii;

template <int dim>
class elastic
{
  public:

    elastic(const Triangulation<dim>   *triang);
     ~elastic() ;

        void  run() ;

  private:
. 
.
.
```

and in another header that includes header:

```
template <int dim>

  elastic<dim>::elastic(const Triangulation<dim>   *triang): dof_handler (triangulation), fe (FE_Q<dim>(1))

  {triangulation.copy_triangulation  (*triang);}
```

and my main is written below:

```
#include "prelim.h"

using namespace dealii;

int main()

{
  deallog.depth_console (0);    
  elastic<2>    *elast_opt();    
  for ( iter=0; iter<5 ; ++iter)    
      elast_opt()->run();    
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get these errors:

```
....../main.cc:16: undefined reference to `elast_opt()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: You bothered to write out a signature, but not to capitalise the word "I". Or anything, actually. How peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

thanks hmjd for response .
 it works just as i eliminate some parts in prelim and setup header as :
 in prelim header:

```
public: elastic(/*const Triangulation<dim> *triang*/);
 ~elastic() ; 
void run() ; in setup header :
 elastic<dim>::elastic(/*const Triangulation<dim> *triang*/): dof_handler (triangulation), 

fe (FE_Q<dim>(1)) 
{/*triangulation.copy_triangulation (*triang);*/}
```

but these parts must not be deleted and actually i want to know what's the matter with these parts.

my apology i forgot to mention that with aplying changes suggested and without eliminating beforementioned parts the error is changed to :

```
 ==============debug========= main.cc  ->  main.g.o main.g.o
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:11:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘elastic<2>::elastic()’
main.cc:11:43: note: candidates are:
setup.h:12:3: note: elastic<dim>::elastic(const dealii::Triangulation<dim>*) [with int dim = 2]
setup.h:12:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prelim.h:38:7: note: elastic<2>::elastic(const elastic<2>&)
prelim.h:38:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make: *** [main.g.o] Error 1
s
```